# Inserting non-default tab stops into a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, richtextbox

Is it possible to write code to insert a non-default tab stop into the document of a RichTextBox? For example, the equivalent of the MS-Word right-tab or decimal-tab?

Thanks,
Firoz